# Need at least 10 Reputation to post an Image, please explain

Tags: support, reputation, images

I am trying to post an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22060684/3330969) to a question on Stack Overflow. I get this response

> You need at least 10 reputation to post an image

What on earth does it mean, what do I need to do to post an image with my answer ?

Comment: Please have a look at the *help* menu at the top of this screen. There's a *Discuss the workings and policies of this site* link

Comment: It means you must be more trusted on the site in order to place a possibly inappropriate image with your question.

Comment: And by the way, you can link to an image, that will be good enough.

Comment: if someone doesn't know that what is reputation? and how to earn it. then why people are giving them down vote or close vote? rather then they can give the answer.

Comment: @Nimesh I voted to close as duplicate, because it is a duplicate *and* I made a short tailored answer to help OP. There were reasons to downvote : OP directly posted on SO main without looking the help and sounded aggressive (*"What on earth"*) which is rarely the best way to get help.

Answer (score 4):

Right now, just paste a link to your image. This will be good enough.

And if it's relevant and the question is good quality enough, some user will probably inline it directly for a greater comfort of other readers.

If your question is good, and if you answer a few questions yourself, you'll gain those missing 10 points fast enough, so you'll be able to directly include the image. This isn't really a privilege per se, more like a small protection against spammer and trolls.